# How to open new tab in JavaScript without switching to the new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open a new tab using javascript without switching to the new tab?
For example, when a user clicks on a link a new tab is to be opened, but the user should stay on the current tab.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The web browser automatically focuses on the new tab, but you can call the focus back:

```
function openWindow( url )
{
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  window.focus();
}

<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="javascript:openWindow(this.href);return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Re `focus`: No in my experience. Not with Chrome, anyway (http://jsbin.com/aboluk/2) -- but they're not much harm in trying.

Comment: @josh3736: That's interesting. I'm still on 14 (on Linux) and it doesn't. So basically: You can't rely on it. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Works on Chrome 14 Windows and Chrome 15 Ubuntu.  (Perhaps it's something strange going on in your setup?)  At any rate, it doesn't work on any version of Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Works for me with Chrome 14 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Josh: ...and works in Chrome 15 on Ubuntu 11.10 (as of my previous comment it would have been Chrome 14 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS).

Comment: The following works on Chrome: `var w=window.open(url,'_blank'); w.focus();` I guess `window.focus();` puts the focus back on the current window instead of the new one.

Comment: The above code is opened a new window, not a new tab in same browser. what's the code for opening a new tab in the same browser?

Comment: As of Chrome 23 on Linux, this doesn't work, the new window gets and keeps focus.

Comment: Does not work in firefox as of Jan 2023

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, you can't currently do that -- but you can get close. You can open a new *window*, and if you do that without specifying any window dimensions or window features, most modern browsers will open a new tab instead (depending on the user's preferences, but then, you want to do what the user prefers anyway, right?). So just `window.open(url)` or `window.open(url, name)` if you're going to use the name for something. Be sure to do this in direct response to a user-initiated event, otherwise the browser's pop-up blocker will probably...block the pop-up. :-)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aboluk)

Regarding keeping focus on your window...good luck with that. You can call `window.focus()` after `window.open(...)`, but in my experience it doesn't usually work.

Throwing it out there: If you make the thing the user interacts with a genuine link with a URL, the *user* can decide whether to open it in a new tab, a new window, whatever and whether to give it focus (if they're sophisticated enough to know Shift+Click and Ctrl+Shift+Click, or the right-click menu).

Comment: Note that in IE, this does open in a new window, not a new tab.

Comment: @josh3736: That depends on what version of IE you're using, and in newer versions, what your settings are.

Comment: Forgot I had changed that setting in IE9.  Specifically, `window.open()` causes a new tab in IE unless Options > Tabs Settings > "Let IE decide how pop-ups should open" is changed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in ALL browsers, but you can do this in Chrome if you implement browser's extension.
How to manipulate with tabs in Chrome by javascript:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

```
chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)
    Creates a new tab. Note: This function can be used without requesting the 'tabs' permission in the manifest.
Parameters
    **createProperties** ( object )
    **windowId** ( optional integer )
       The window to create the new tab in. Defaults to the current window.
    **index** ( optional integer )
       The position the tab should take in the window. The provided value will be clamped to between zero and the number of tabs in the window.
    **url** ( optional string )
       The URL to navigate the tab to initially. Fully-qualified URLs must include a scheme (i.e.    'http://www.google.com', not 'www.google.com'). Relative URLs will be relative to the current page within the extension. Defaults to the New Tab Page.
    **selected** ( optional boolean )
       Whether the tab should become the selected tab in the window. Defaults to true
    pinned ( optional boolean )
       Whether the tab should be pinned. Defaults to false
    **callback** ( optional function )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is user specific settings, you cannot change this behavior from JS.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(a) {
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('href', location.href);
    a.dispatchEvent((function(e) {
        e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                         true, false, false, false, 0, null);
        return e
    }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))
}(document.createElement('a')))
```

Comment: Which browser is this for?

Answer (score 1):

For me, using

```
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

worked perfectly. What this does depends on what browser you are using, what operating system, and your personal preferences.

Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Firefox all opened a new tab. Sorry if this doesn't work for you.

(Just realized that this is an old thread)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isMobile = false;
        if (
          /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent
          ) ||
          /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4)
          )
        ) {
          isMobile = true;
        }


    if (isMobile) {
    window.location.assign(url);
    } else {
window.open(url);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Post is old but without any 100% correct answer.

SOLUTION FOR ALL BROWSERs:

you can open new tab to **same domain** URLs via :

```
window.open("newurl.php", "_blank");
```

and for cross-domain new tabs, you must create a simple local script, like this :

in new file "redirect.php" you pass a parameter (target new tab url ) like this

```
<?php
   $newURL=$_GET['u'];
   header('Location: '.$newURL);
؟>
```

and you can create a new tab with any target url with :

```
window.open("redirect.php?u=http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

:)

its my solution in my website. and work with any

Comment: the focus is still on the new tab. Please the question properly.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question properly and could also lead to some issues further down the line.
https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/11-Client_Side_Testing/04-Testing_for_Client_Side_URL_Redirect

Answer (score -3):

in mac: `Cmd+click` and in windows: `ctrl+click` will open new tabs in the background. Perhaps this is an issue of user training rather than something that needs to be solved programmatically?

source:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Ctab-and-window-shortcuts%2Cmouse-shortcuts