# How do I simulate clicking a link that opens in a new tab/window using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a link that opens in a new tab with _blank:

```
<a href="new_page.html" target="_blank">link</a>
```

I'd like to be able to 'click' on this from Javascript. I know I could do `document.location=...` but the problem here is the new tab part. Is this possible?

Comment: If you just want to click on the link in Javascript, there are certainly ways. If you want to open a new tab using javascript alone, you may be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924232/open-new-tab-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually open a new window *or tab* using `window.open`. So instead of setting `location`, just call `window.open` and pass only the URL, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#your_a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.open($(this).attr("href"), this.target);
}
```

You could use any name for target, `preventDefault()` if you want to override the link actions completely

Comment: Ah forgot to mention, this will open a new window in old browsers like IE 7, new tab in everything else

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to simulate click, you can give a id to the anchor tag and call jQuery click() on that element.

```
<a id="mylink" href="new_page.html" target="_blank">link</a>
```

and in script

```
$("#mylink").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

to "simulate" the click you trigger the click event:

HTML:

```
<a href="new_page.html" target="_blank" id="mylink">click me</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#mylink").trigger("click");
```

-or-

```
$("#mylink").click();
```

Using 'trigger' allows you to pass in extra parameters if you bind a function to the click event. See the jQuery 'trigger' documentation for more info: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/