# Reporting services open a report in new tab

Tags: javascript, url, service, tabs, report

I need to open a URL link in another tab.
I have tested this code that opens in a new window.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com'))"
```

But, how can I open it in another tab ..?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open new tab in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924232/open-new-tab-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost got it

```
 ="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank'))"
```