# How does Gmail force itself to become the active tab when it's done loading?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I've never seen another website do this and it's interesting behavior. To recreate it, open a new tab in Safari and go to mail.google.com. While it's loading switch to another tab and wait. Once Gmail has finished it's ajax loading it fires what I presume to be a javascript event to force it to become the active tab.

Does anyone know what the javascript event is? Is it possible it's not javascript?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Chrome Linux (26.0.1410.63)

Comment: Just Safari(read Webkit), as Chrome is built on different core

Comment: *Does* happen for me in Safari under OSX (but not Chrome under the same).

Comment: I Believe it is a browser functionality and varies between different browsers. for instance I know firefox has "Switch to tab" feature that automatically switches you over to the a new tab

Comment: @t3hn00b Chrome has been WebKit for its entire history (Chrome 28 will be built upon 'Blink', but Blink is just a fork of WebKit- 27 is currently the latest version).

Comment: @PrakashChennupati Is the switch to tab feature available via javascript?

Comment: @MatthewForr Yes, Please have a look at my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab/15818960#15818960

Answer (score 2):

Everything that you need about safari javascript extentions is there:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html

I checked, they talk about how to set a tab active.

Comment: I think this is the right function to call as this is talking about extensions. I don't have any Google extensions installed in Safari.

Comment: It's built-in, YOU write the extension ;)