# Why does window open sometimes open a new tab and sometimes a popup?

Tags: javascript

After making a rest request to a webservice, I want to redirect my user to the url returned by the web service.

I am using `window.open(url, "_blank");` which has, when I've used it in the past, simply opened up a new tab. However, for some reason that I can't get to the bottom of, my redirect is being treated as a popup. Instead of opening a new tab, Chrome actually creates a separate small window.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to why chrome would decide to create a separate window as opposed to just opening a new tab.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you must be testing this on 2 separate browsers

Comment: What version of Chrome? Since the latest version there appears to have been some terrible updates to the way they handle popups and whatnot. Might be completely unrelated, but worth noting, I think.

Comment: I'm using chrome version 30

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15818960/2539014) from another question. When a javascript event is initiated by the user, `open()` opens the link in a new tab. Otherwise, it's opened in a popup window. So if the user clicks something that triggers `open()`, a new tab will open. If you set a timeout or try to open a link after some other event, like an ajax response, a new window will open.