# Open New Tab- Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab), I looked around my Google Chrome settings for how to allow javascript to open new tabs without user interaction but I couldn't find the setting. I'm using Google Chrome on my iMac, if it makes a difference.

I tried searching for something using the [Chrome Support Site](https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=help&ctx=settings#topic=3227046) but couldn't find anything that really helped.

Does anyone know how to edit this setting?

Comment: And, what is your question?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, "Does anyone know how to edit this setting?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab

Comment: The first answer says that there's a setting

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question then, in your core javascript file you can add this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rX8GP/2/)

Comment: @RahilWazir that doesn't matter I guess because it works fine without that as well. It's like a hidden parameter which is always present with the functions.

Comment: It does matter otherwise it will throw an error: `e is not defined`. Well you've removed it so.

Comment: This requires user interaction. I was hoping that there was a setting, as a user on the thread I posted in the question said there was, that would allow this without user interaction

Comment: @Alex how would it? The user would definitely need to click a link.

Comment: For my purpose, the user isn't clicking anything. It's complicated but trust me, it all happens dynamically.

Comment: And the original question was if and where is the setting for this