# How to open popup Page in New tab

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using below code for open page in popup window.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(Page), "OpenWindow",     "window.open('URL');", True)
```

But i want to page open in New Tab. Can any one help me in that.

Comment: Could you please specify which browser you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make the JavaScript call a user initiated event.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab) question and answer for further details (specifically, see point 3 in the answer).

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a3STP/).

`<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="openWindow()" />`

`function openWindow() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank');
}`

Comment: @angsuf yr answer is good. i have smiler prob --> can u say how to do this operation from code file because this thing causing popup and that popup block by browser.. we have to manually allow popup then after it work..

Comment: @Shirish do you mean to open a new window from the code behind or do you mean to create the JavaScript function and set the onclick attributes from the code behind?

Comment: @angsuf yes i want to open new window from code behind, I am using like this function..  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open('../default.aspx','_blank');", true); but every time it cause popup and browser blocker block popup in all browsers..

Comment: @Shirish your code is just running the script to open the popup on the page load. A user will need to initiate the popup using a control that calls the JavaScript function. The answer I provided is relevant to you also. Point 6 `6. Some popup blockers will allow windows opened from user initiated events, but not those opened otherwise.`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('WebForm2.aspx', '_blank');", true);
```

or

```
 string url = "WebForm2.aspx";
 string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

I tried In Google Chrome its working but Not In Firefox
In aspx Code

```
 <asp:Button Text="" OnClick="Button1_Click" ID="Button1" runat="server" />
```

In C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string queryString = "test.aspx" ;
      string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "','_blank');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
}
```

In VB

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim queryString As String = "test.aspx" 
    Dim newWin As String = "window.open('" + queryString + "','_blank');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", newWin, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is not working. I tried this code but page is not open.
My code is working but it open Popup window i want to open New Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this with your script

```
window.open('URL', '_blank')
```

and I think it's browser setting that decide whether to open new window or tab. Have a look in to that as well.

found this; If nothing works try this
[link](http://www.computershopper.com/feature/50-windows-7-tips-tweaks-and-secrets/open-a-link-in-a-new-tab-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: i am using Chrome browser and i have done the setting.

Comment: Try using IE and see if its the same. This is defenitely some browser setting

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..working for me in all browsers...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open(

'URL','_blank','height=600px,width=600px,scrollbars=1');", true);
```

Please Mark as answer if it satisfies you..

Answer (score 0):

check this example for you,

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(btnsave, this.GetType(), "Open",
"window.open('GenerateDCNoPrint.aspx?indentno=" + ddlindentno.SelectedItem.Text + 
"&orderno=" + ddlindentno.SelectedValue + "&lorryno=" + txtlorryno.Text.Trim() + 
"&depaturetime=" + txtdeparture.Text.Trim() + "&date=" + txtdate.Text + "', 
'_blank','dependent,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=0,height=600');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and tried many solutions but finally, this works for me.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "newWindow", "window.open('google.com','_blank','status=1,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=700,height=400');", true);
```