# Using window.open repeatedly produces unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html

My browser allows any website to show pop-ups (made using `window.open`).

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/","_blank");
```

The above code opens `google.com` on a new tab.

---

However, when I use `window.open` repeatedly like this:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/","_blank");
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/","_blank");
window.open("http://www.example.com/","_blank");
```

Now, `google.com` is opened on a new tab, while `facebook.com` and `example.com` are opened as pop-up windows. I actually want to have the 3 links to open in new tabs but I can't achieve that.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab) question.

Comment: @jamantaka Not at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised the second and third get opened at all. (They don't on Chrome, it blocks them; but I do see the behavior you describe if I disable the blocker.)

You'll need to provide separate UI elements (buttons, whatever) to open each window individually, so that each `window.open` call is triggered by a separate end-user action, rather than opening several windows in response to a *single* user action. Hopefully that will give you the behavior you desire for each individual window. Although you don't have control over whether something opens in a new window or a tab, most browsers default to new tabs these days (and most have an option for users to change it) unless you supply the third argument to `window.open`, in which case they *may* open a new window instead using the settings you pass in that argument.

Since Chrome does this unusual thing with the second and third calls, limiting yourself to a single `open` per user action should work in most cases, as in most cases the default is a new tab, not a new window.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and they *do* open

Comment: That's because the other pop-ups were blocked by your browser, I think

Comment: What do you mean by `suggest to the browser that it use a new window by supplying the third parameter to window.open`?

Comment: @user3553493: I mean if you give the third argument to `window.open` (the one where you specify what window controls there should be, the size of the window, etc.), the browser will usually (not always) open a new window rather than a new tab. That won't help you if your goal is to open new tabs.

Comment: If my goal is to open new tabs, what should I put in the third parameter then? I tried `fullscreen=yes` but in the end, none of the links were opened in new tabs.

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: @user3553493: As far as I know, there's nothing you can put in the third argument that will tell the browser to use a new tab; putting things there usually makes the browser use a new window instead. As I said in the answer, since using a new tab is the default in most cases, you'll have to open these windows individually, each in response to its own user event.