# How to open two tabs window in Opera/Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#" onclick="return openTwoWindowTab();">Click Here</a>

<script>
function openTwoWindowTab(){
  window.open('www.google.com','_blank');
  window.open('www.yahoo.com','_blank');
}
</script>
```

Here i am trying to open two window tabs on click a link.

1) It is working fine in Mozilla Firefox 18.0.2

2) But in google chrome only one tab is opening. Version 35.0.1916.114

3) In Opera also only one tab is opening. Version latest one

It is very critical issue for me...any help/suggestion....

Comment: Possible duplicate? Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript and here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to do this:

```
function openTwoWindowTab() {
    // create object to serve the urls
    var obj = {
        0: 'http://www.google.com',
        1: 'http://www.yahoo.com'
    };
    setTimeout(function () { // use setTimeout function to wait for other window to open
                             // otherwise one window will be opened in the browser window
        for (var a = 0; a <= Object.keys(obj).length - 1; a++) {
            window.open(obj[a], '_blank');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5m34e/)

Comment: In chrome both are opening in new window....In Opera one tab is opening and at right bottom one message block is coming "Pop-up block from ..." click here to open....when i will click on message pop-up then new tab is opening...Mozilla---working fine...@jai

Comment: @user3676578 see for security reason and usability perspective browsers don't allow multiple popups in quick succession so you need to allow popups to be opened for this particular site where you want it to be placed. as i have allowed jsfiddle to open popups at my client machine.

Comment: when you see `"Pop-up block from ..." click here to open....` message from browser then you can select options available there. try clicking the message in the browser and BTW i don't have Opera browser in my machine so i can't test it for now.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
   <a href="javascript:DoubleOpen('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com');">Click Here</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function DoubleOpen(site1, site2) { 
    window.open(site1); 
    window.location = site2; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: In Opera one tab is opening and at right bottom one message block is coming "Pop-up block from ..." click here to open....when i will click on message pop-up then new tab is opening.

In Chrome one tab and one new window is opening....

Comment: check again @user3676578

Comment: now in Parent page only first link is coming ... Actually i want to open two new _blank tabs with parent page should exists there only...@cyberoot

Comment: i try to find bro , let' me think