# Is there a way to close a tab in WebDriver or Protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Is there a way to physically close a tab via Protractor or WebDriver?

I ask because while I know how to [switch tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798020/protractor-switch-to-previous-tab) programmatically, but it does not bring the active tab to the foreground. I can't always tell what is going on in my E2E tests that run on SauceLabs because when I view the screen casts it is showing the tab that I navigated away from, not the active one.

Am I going about this incorrectly?

```
it('should do something in the previous tab', function(done) {
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
        // do something
        expect(something).toEqual(thisThing);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Switch to the new opened tab.
2. Close the current windows (in this case, the new tab).
3. Switch back to the first window.

   ```
   browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
   browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
   browser.driver.close();
   browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
   });
   ```

Comment: `close()` closed the tab for me when I opened an image. However, not sure still!

Comment: @Aaron good to know, is it working for both firefox and chrome? Thanks.

Comment: great solution for handling multiple browser windows. Not documented on Protractor's API page (at least not that we could find today -http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser ).

Comment: C# version 
  var tabs = driver.WindowHandles;
                        if (tabs.Count > 1)
                        {
                            driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
                            driver.Close();
                            driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[0]);
                        }

Comment: @MarkRowe: Is this a tested and working code? If yes, then I can edit my answer to include the C# version

Comment: Here, I'm able to close a new tab which was opened form another tab. But when I come back to old tab, a dialog is opened there and I am not able to click on buttons of that.

Comment: Did you switch to that dialog  to perform some actions?

Answer (score 19):

First of all, **selenium does not provide a reliable cross-browser API to work with browser tabs**. A common approach to open or close a tab (although not quite reliable) is to invoke browser shortcuts for Chrome:

- open tab: `CTRL`/`COMMAND` + `T`
- close tab: `CTRL`/`COMMAND` + `W`

In protractor, find the `body` element and "send keys" to it:

```
var body = element(by.tagName("body"));
body.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "t"))
body.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "w"))
```

Or, using `browser.actions()`:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('t').perform();
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('w').perform();
```

---

Also, to open a new tab, there is an interesting hack (introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105388/771848)), which basically injects a new `a` element into the page and invokes `click` mouse event:

```
function openNewTab (url) {
    return browser.driver.executeScript(function(url) {(
        function(a, url){
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('href', url);
            a.dispatchEvent((function(e){
                e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
                return e;
            }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))
        }(document.createElement('a'), url)
    );
    }, url)
};
```

---

There is also [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) function, but it would not close the tab if it was not opened via `window.open()` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076307/771848)). In other words, if this is a tab you manually open, then you can use `window.open() -> window.close()` approach with the help of `browser.executeScript()`.

Comment: using `window.open()` do you know how to open a reference to an existing tab that was previously opened using `window.open()`? I have a chrome extension running in the 2nd tab to capture HTTP headers and I can't figure out how to how to get back to that tab to check them when something breaks.

Answer (score 5):

C# Version of Sakshi's answer:

```
   var tabs = driver.WindowHandles;
   if (tabs.Count > 1)
   {
       driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
       driver.Close();
       driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[0]);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Close all tabs except first one and switch to first tab:

```
var tabs = driver.WindowHandles; // 

foreach (var tab in tabs)
{
     // "tab" is a string like "CDwindow-6E793DA3E15E2AB5D6AE36A05344C68"
     if (tabs[0] != tab) 
     {                                    
         driver.SwitchTo().Window(tab); 
         driver.Close();
     }
}

driver.SwitchTab(tabs[0]); // Switch to first tab
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); // Switch to default frame
```

Pay attention to last two lines, they are need to avoid such errors like `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found`

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`driver.close`
and then switch to active tab `driver.SwitchTo().Window(m_driver.WindowHandles.First());` or any another available tab

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for selenium with Java

```
ArrayList<String> switchTabs= new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(switchTabs.get(1));
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(switchTabs.get(0));
```

Note: close the tabs based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

As Sakshi Singla answered, `browser.driver.close()` is worked for me ,Please see the sample `spec.js` for a Protractor Jasmine.

```
describe('Window handle', function() {  
      //Each single it function is a test script
      it('Navigae to the site', function() {
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);     
        browser.driver.get('http://demo.automationtesting.in/Windows.html');    

      });

      it('handle the new window', function() {
          //This will open a new popup
            element(by.buttonText('click')).click();
          var winHandles=browser.getAllWindowHandles();
          winHandles.then(function(handles) 
          {
              var parentWindow=handles[0];
              var popUpWindow=handles[1];
              browser.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
//verify title in the new window
              expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Sakinalium | Home');
              element(by.linkText('Contact')).click();
//To close the popup
               browser.driver.close();
             //verify title in the parent window
              browser.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
              expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Frames & windows');             
              element(by.linkText('Open Seperate Multiple Windows')).click();
              browser.sleep(7500);
          })
          });


})
```

Answer (score 0):

if use keyboard library with selenium its very simple for switch on tab and close or etc :

first install keyboard library :

```
pip install keyboard
```

second use keyboard for close tab in code for example :

```
    def change_tab_my_func(self, number):
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[number])

    change_tab_my_func(0)   #your tab index    
    keyboard.send('ctrl+w')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
await browser.executeScript('window.close()');
```

just don't forget to switch to the working tab

```
let tabs = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
await browser.switchTo().window(tabs[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know for sure, which tab is the newly opened one; if you know that the URL of your desired tab contains some unique part, you can do something like this in C#:

```
string uniqueURL = "your unique text in URL of the tab you want to keep";
var windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
if(windowHandles.Count > 1)
{
       foreach(var tab in windowHandles)
       {
              driver.SwitchTo().Window(tab);
              if(!driver.Url.Contains(uniqueURL))
              {
                    driver.Close();
              }
       }

       driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using the command below to close the current tab after opening the link in new tab

```
Instance.Driver2.SwitchTo().Window(Instance.Driver2.WindowHandles[1]).Close();
```

Then, you can switch to the last tab by issue the command:

```
Instance.Driver2.SwitchTo().Window(Instance.Driver2.WindowHandles[0]);
```