# protractor switchTo target tab stays "unfocused"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have the problem that `switchTo` doesn't "focus" the tab in question. I receive the array of present tabs with `getAllWindowHandles` and protractor is directing the actions to the right tab, but it never pops into foreground. Therefore elements never get visible. Am I doing something wrong here? (protractor 2.0.0, current Chrome)

```
var tabs;

function switchToUser1() {
    return browser.switchTo().window(tabs[0]);
}

function switchToUser2() {
    return browser.switchTo().window(tabs[1]);
}

beforeAll(function() {
    browser.executeScript("window.open('about:blank');");
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
        tabs = handles;
    });
    switchToUser1();
    userPO.login(login1);
    switchToUser2();
    userPO.login(login2);
});
```

Comment: I had an issue similar to this as well if you want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502255/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-tab-in-webdriver-or-protractor

Comment: I've already taken a look at that question. My problem is not to open the new tab. Also the new tab immediately has focus. My problem is that I can't switch between them.

Comment: The problem still exists, but I found a way that the tests are running. As you can see in my question, I open the tab at the very beginning. Even before page loading. Now I login with the first user, then open a tab and login with the second user there. After that I can execute tests in both tabs even if it is in the background.