# switch back to previous tab in browser by using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to get the second tab in my window browser by using below code but it is not working for me. Can any one suggest me easy way.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {  
  //Code for switchTo one Tab to another Tab in Same Browser
  browser.switchTo().window('http://localhost:4200/home-unauth'); 
});
```

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505926/5042982.
You capture all window handles after resolving the promise and then switch back to initial handle i.e. handle[0].

Answer (score -1):

Resolved promise of `getAllWindowHandles` returns an array of tabs uuid. You even don't need to decode the values; new tab is added as last parameter of that array.

Try that - switch to second tab:

```
return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((allTabs) => {
   return browser.switchTo().window(allTabs[1]);
});
```