# Python Selenium - Cannot close tab using google shortcuts

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a little selenium project, but I got some issues.

So what I need to do is to click on a link to open it in a new tab, and whenever I have taken the information I need to close that tab and go into the next one. `driver.close()` does not work as it gives me the error: `Message: no such window: target window already closed`. So I intstead tried this (saw this while researching):
`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')`, and I also tried with adding `Keys.F4`, but nothing worked.

It seems to work for other people, so why not for me?

Code:

```
def cpuFunc():
    i = 0
    print("Launching CPU")
    cpu = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=option)
    cpu.get('https://www.komplett.se/category/11204/datorutrustning/datorkomponenter/processor')
    cpu.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/button').click()
    #while i < 10:
    #    cpu.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
    #    i += 1
    #    time.sleep(0.5)
    #print("At bottom: CPU")
    cpu.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    link = cpu.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/form/div[1]/a')
    ActionChains(cpu).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    window = cpu.window_handles[-1]
    cpu.switch_to.window(window)
    title = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/section/div[1]/h1/span").text
    price = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
    btn = cpu.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/button')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    cpu.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    core = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td").text
    thread = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td").text
    cache = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td").text
    clock = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td").text
    turbo = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[8]/td").text
    socket = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[9]/td").text
    wattage = cpu.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[10]/td").text
    cpu.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w') # Here it shall close
    time.sleep(60000)
enter code here
```

Comment: similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502255/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-tab-in-webdriver-or-protractor

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ActionChains & Keys.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

If MacOs:

```
step_1 = ActionChains(cpu)
step_1.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
```

If Windows:

```
step_1 = ActionChains(cpu)
step_1.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

Hope it helps, if issues please comment.

Comment: Does not work for me, its so strange. I will try a few other methods I found and try to use latest chromedriver (using latest version gave me errors last time I tried).

Comment: what version of chrome and chrome driver are you using?

Comment: 87.0.4280.88 @jiya

Comment: Nope, trying with chromedriver 88 does not work for me and `step_1.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')` doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Just tried Chromedriver 88 and it's not working for me as well... have you tried 87?
for me, it's working like a charm in 87

Comment: yeah I am using 87 right now. But it does not close the window. I've tried to use a different website and a brand new py file with only that. I will be trying with firefox soon to see if that works.

Comment: No luck on firefox either.

Comment: wouldn't there be a `.perform()` at the end of the `ActionChain` to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

Driver.close() worked for me after also fixed a lot of those full xpaths which are easily breakable and added webdriver waits for stability in finding elements.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(cpu, 10)
cpu.get('https://www.komplett.se/category/11204/datorutrustning/datorkomponenter/processor')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn-large primary'][@type='submit']"))).click()
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form > div:nth-child(1) > a")))
ActionChains(cpu).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(1)
window = cpu.window_handles[-1]
cpu.switch_to.window(window)
title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-main-info__info > h1 > span"))).text
price = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-price > span"))).text
print(title,price)
btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.product-section.technical-details.col-xs-12 > button")))
btn.click()
table2 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table:nth-child(2) > tbody")))
core = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[2]/td").text
thread = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[3]/td").text
cache = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[4]/td").text
clock = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[7]/td").text
turbo = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[8]/td").text
socket = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[9]/td").text
wattage = table2.find_element_by_xpath("./tr[10]/td").text
cpu.close()
print(core,thread,cache,clock,turbo,socket,wattage)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! Will give this a try and explore a bit with the code you sent. Again, thanks!