# window.open opens popup instead of new tab after opening action sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ember.js, ember-data

On click of close button in action sheet I'm trying to create new tab.  After it opens new popup in chrome.  But when i try to open new tab from normal page, it opens in new tab.

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

But I want to open new tab instead on popup.  Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome, Javascript, window.open in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab)

Comment: please take a look into these q&a:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.open u can use this

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
```