# Open in new tab chrome for printing purpose

Tags: javascript

I want to open my print screen option in a new tab instead of a new window.

Here is my javascript code

```
$scope.PrintWindow = function(divName,method) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('Print', method, 'fullscreen=yes');
  popupWin.document.open()
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');

  popupWin.document.close();
           popupWin.focus();
}
```

_self opens in same window

_target and _newtab opens in new window. I want it to be in new tab.

Comment: You can't force a new tab, rather than a new window, as it's down to the browser and possibly user settings.

Comment: This has been discussed already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab

Comment: I was using fullscreen=yes which was opening a new window always.Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removed fullscreen=yes and it solved my problem.**

```
  $scope.PrintWindow = function(divName,method) {
      var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      var popupWin = window.open('Print', method,);
      popupWin.document.open()
      popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');

      popupWin.document.close();
               popupWin.focus();
    }
```