# On blur confirm it

Tags: javascript

On blur I am trying to get a new tab to open only after user confirms to do this. However, I cannot see this happening and no confirm dialog is triggered. I am using the below and have tried other scripts too but cannot find how to do this:

```
 $(window).blur(function() {
      confirmit() { 
      var closeit= confirm("Would you like to see our exclusive offers?"); 
      if (closeit == true) {
        window.open("http://NEWURLHERE.com" target="_blank");
      }
      else {
        window.close();
      }
    };
})
```

Comment: Syntax error after `confirmit()`.

Comment: remove the `confirmit() {` and the closing `}` of it.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but is this question only related to jQuery? If yes, we can add a tag

Answer (score 0):

first `define confirmit` and for that, add the keyword `function` before `confirmit`.
Then after closing `}`, call it by `confirmit();`
Also, you can't pass arguments simply to a `window.open` `function` like you use in `<a` tag by seperating using `spaces`. Just put a comma(,) to seperate arguments.
*Remove `target=` and just pass the value.*
However it will not work in IE. Check here to see Why?  [Chrome, Javascript, window.open in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab)

Check the below code. Run it, click on the output screen and then click outside

```js
$(window).blur(function() {
   function confirmit() { 
      var closeit= confirm("Would you like to see our exclusive offers?"); 
      if (closeit == true) {
        window.open("http://NEWURLHERE.com",'_blank');
      }
      else {
        window.close();
      }
    };
    confirmit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers. Most work but the new tab gets blocked by popup blocker. As user confirms to open why does it still block? I don't want it to block is there any way around this

Comment: It is either a browser security feature  or done by a pop up blocker. Glad it helped you mate. Consider marking it as answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if you've included the jQuery library in your code. I was able to reproduce exactly whatever you stated.

```js
$(window).blur(function() {
  var closeit = confirm("Would you like to see our exclusive offers?");
  if (closeit == true) {
    window.open("http://NEWURLHERE.com",
      target = "_blank");
  } else {
    window.close();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```js
var confirmit = function(){ 
      var closeit= confirm("Would you like to see our exclusive offers?"); 
      if (closeit == true) {
        alert("You chose Ok");
        // window.open("http://NEWURLHERE.com" target="_blank");
      }
      else {
        alert("You chose Cancel");
        // window.close();
      }
    }
 
 $(window).blur(function() {
    confirmit();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).blur(function() {
      var closeit= confirm("Would you like to see our exclusive offers?"); 
      if (closeit == true) {
        window.open("http://NEWURLHERE.com", target="_blank");
      }
      else {
        window.close();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---