# window.location.href - Link in new tab

Tags: javascript

```
var notification = new Notification(theTitle, options);
notification.onclick = function() { 
    window.location.href = theLink; //redirects to the specified link
};
```

I am trying  to open a new tab by clicking the notification box. Using the above code the redirection works fine. But I want to open the link in a new tab. How Can I do this?

Comment: ``window.open``

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab

Comment: window.open(theLink);
This worked. Thank You 
@DonaldWu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
notification.onclick = function() { 
    window.open(theLink);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

try `window.open("page url")` hope it works