# Replacement clickable link

Tags: javascript, click

I should be able to click on second text which leads me to a new website of my choice in a new tab.

```js
var search = "First text";
var replacement = "Second text";

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.open() function with an extra parameter (target) set 
as '_blank' to achieve this. Although you can't control whether it will be a new tab, as it is based on the local browser settings the user is working on, however you can force it to open in a popup.

Refer to this answer: [Chrome, Javascript, window.open in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15818960/5810092)

Comment: Yes i understand that but how to exactly do it?

Comment: Alright, so I think I understood your question wrong, do you want to replace First Text with basically a link?

Comment: If that is so, then instead of replacing with "Second Text", you could replace with "<a href='url' target='_blank">Second Text</a>"