# Window.open problems in html

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am trying to open a new window with a button. The window needs to have a specific height and width. Whenever I click the "open" button it just opens a completely new tab.

```js
var aWindow;

function openWindow() {
  aWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height = 200");
}

function closeWindow() {
  if (aWindow) {
    aWindow.close();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="openWindow();">Open</button>
  <button onclick="closeWindow();">Close</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where should I add it?

Comment: Have you seen this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: I'll take a look at it right now.

Comment: I think this will give / get you the answer you are looking for: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726803/1971378)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
 window.open('https://www.google.co.in/','_blank','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=10px, height=20px')
```

**[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/jijomonkmgm/d9uh1k7y/1/)**

Comment: That isn't popping up a window when I enter it into the the code then run it

Comment: @JohnKosmalski : its working please check the demo link

Comment: Could the issue be me using chrome?

Comment: @JohnKosmalski : Iam tested its on chrome

Comment: When I click the link it opens up a new tab.

Comment: Could it be the settings I have on chrome? Do I need to change anything?

Comment: try to use _blank. check my updated answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab

Comment: Got it! That linked answered it for me.

Comment: your are wlcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=300px,height=300px');
```

Try this code tested

Comment: The same issue happens

Comment: Are you testing in firefox ?

Comment: I'm testing it on a virtual machine then running it in chrome. I've never had problems with the virtual machine before

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Open a Popup Window" onclick="popupFunction('https://stackoverflow.com')">

<script>
    // Popup window function
    function popupFunction(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
    }
</script>
```