# Open page in a new tab using php and jquery

Tags: jquery

I having some problem to open page in a new tab using php. Actually once a button is clicked on the menu bar it should open in a new tab. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: You'd just need simple javascript, no need for jquery/php

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about PHP.

Example for links:

```
<a href="page.html" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Example for button:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onClick="javascript:window.open('page.html', '_blank');" />
```

Comment: well this is how i did under html

<li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Login/Register</a></li>

Comment: should i add the javascript coding?

Comment: Show me your full code, upload it to jsfiddle or so

Comment: @user3536613 I've updated your code, it works, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/UL6zu/1/ - top links are now okay and active

Comment: can you tell me which part of the code did you update

Comment: @user3536613 look at the links stored in <ul class = "dropdown-menu"> section, there are 4 of them. Compare it to what you had before to see the difference.

Comment: well i have tried but still i have to right click on it then only it opens in a new tab.. if i click on it nothing happens

Comment: So the problem is in the rest of your code. It jsFiddle works for you then my code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like it

```
function openWindow( url )
{
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  window.focus();
}

<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="javascript:openWindow(this.href);return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Reference: [Open new tab in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924232/open-new-tab-in-javascript/7924248#7924248)

Comment: well this works but i have to right click on my browser to open it in a new tab.. are there any ways.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do more then put your **target ="_blank"**

Example:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

show demo.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9EwC/)