# JQuery code to open a link in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I wanted to edit slider buttons of Sydney theme(wordpress) to have separate links for each button and I found the following JQuery code. This code works well but opens the links in the current page. Now, I want to edit this code to open the links in a new tab. How could I do it?

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  //Define the new buttons. Delete the lines you don't need
  var button1 = '<a href="http://www.google.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 1
  var button2 = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 2
  var button3 = '<a href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 3</a>'; //Slide 3
  var button4 = '<a href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 4</a>'; //Slide 4
  var button5 = '<a href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 5</a>'; //Slide 5

  //Hide the default button
  $('.slide-inner a').hide();

  //Add the new buttons. Delete the lines you don't need
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(1) .slide-inner').append(button1); //Slide 1
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(2) .slide-inner').append(button2); //Slide 2
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(3) .slide-inner').append(button3); //Slide 3
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(4) .slide-inner').append(button4); //Slide 4
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(5) .slide-inner').append(button5); //Slide 5
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Comment: use attribute target=_blank in <a> tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open new tab in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924232/open-new-tab-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set target for that.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  //Define the new buttons. Delete the lines you don't need
  var button1 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 1
  var button2 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 2
  var button3 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 3</a>'; //Slide 3
  var button4 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 4</a>'; //Slide 4
  var button5 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 5</a>'; //Slide 5

  //Hide the default button
  $('.slide-inner a').hide();

  //Add the new buttons. Delete the lines you don't need
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(1) .slide-inner').append(button1); //Slide 1
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(2) .slide-inner').append(button2); //Slide 2
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(3) .slide-inner').append(button3); //Slide 3
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(4) .slide-inner').append(button4); //Slide 4
  $('.slide-item:nth-of-type(5) .slide-inner').append(button5); //Slide 5
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `target="_blank"` to all link elements

```
   var button1 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 1
   var button2 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 2
   var button3 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 3</a>'; //Slide 3
   var button4 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 4</a>'; //Slide 4
   var button5 = '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.org" class="roll-button button-slider">Button 5</a>'; //Slide 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`target="_blank"` is what you need:

```
   //Define the new buttons. Delete the lines you don't need
   var button1 = '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>'; //Slide 1
```

etc..

for more information - have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Answer (score 1):

use `target=_blank` attribute of html as

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" class="roll-button button-slider">Read More</a>
```