# Open new tab without navigating using typescript

Tags: typescript

im opening a new tab using typescript but i want it to open without directly navigating to it. Any help?

```
im using this method to open it : newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank')
```

Comment: sorry i edited the question. I want the new tab to open but without being directly redirected to it.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924232/how-to-open-new-tab-in-javascript-without-switching-to-the-new-tab

Comment: already tried, not working. Maybe its a browser compatibility issue